# angularjs ngresource save object with id, will break the url

Tags: angularjs

```
var resource = $resource(h://xxx:9090/rest/users/:id", {id:'@id'})
```

When I post a new one (no id) , the URL will be like

> POST: h://xxx:9090/rest/users

But when I saving an object with id, the URL will be:

> POST: h://xxx:9090/rest/users/111

But I don't have the backend API for h://xxx:9090/rest/users/111

How to controll this in ngresource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a resource in angular, you can override the routes with the "url" parameter:

```
$resource('/rest/users/:id', null,
       {
           // uses normal uri
           'retreive: { method: 'GET' },
            // uses overridden uri
           'specialUpdate': { method:'PUT', url: '/other/restful/route/:id' } 
       });
}]
```

and when it's used in a controller after being injected:

```
userResource.specialUpdate([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
```